# problem in Downloading Microsoft Office

Tags: 18.04, microsoft

I had installed playonlinux to download microsoft office, but the file didnt appear in download file to complete the setup.

Any suggestion?

P.S my PC operates both windows and Ubuntu

Comment: You still have to *download* the Office installer yourself - POL is just a compatibility layer, it doesn't provide the Office installer itself.

Answer (score 1):

The current [Office Installer may be found here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-office-offline-installer-f0a85fe7-118f-41cb-a791-d59cef96ad1c). Different versions of the [Office Installer](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=31) have different ratings from http://Winehq.com, so without the version you intend to use, it's difficult to respond accurately. Please note that the applications ([Word](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10), [Excel](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11), [PowerPoint](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13), et al.) have their own ratings

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get office 365 working in POL.

crossover runs office 365 desktop apps fine though. For me, I got the 64 bit office 365 installer from my online office 365 account. The install button which downloads the installer appears on the app page, but only if you are logged in from a windows machine or spoof your user agent string (there are firefox extensions for this). If you spoof the user agent string, use win7 64 bit.

Once you get the 64 bit installer, install it with crossover and bobs your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's strange that you didn't just install Microsoft Office from the official website. Maybe you decided to install an unlicensed version? This solution can often cause problems. Previously, I also had crashes in office and other microsoft programs because I used unlicensed versions of this program. I recently bought a key and I noticed that after activating office on my new computer with a license key , all the problems I encountered disappeared . Maybe if you also did not buy an official registration key, then this is the reason for the installation error?